# Is this for assistants only, excluding automated provers?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, off-topic, scope

Do automated theorem provers fall under the scope of this new Stack Exchange sub-site, as well as Proof Assistants?

Comment: Also [relevant Area 51 discussion](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32621/197295)

Answer (score 19):

My opinion is that we should be welcoming to people coming from related areas. What is the point of gatekeeping a site that has only just been created?

If and when the automated theorem proving people start to dominate this site, they can get one of their own. Until then, let's talk to them. Who knows, perhaps we have something in common.

Answer (score 8):

> Do automated theorem provers fall under the scope of this new Stack Exchange as well as proof assistants?

Since the site is in private beta at present and the purpose of private beta is to  let the community shape the content by voting, ask any question you feel is relevant.

New questions that expand the scope of the site are ones I particularly look for and give upvotes to see more of them.

Questions with tags that are new get more of my attention.

Also don't close a question with a few down votes. There was one question that had two down votes when I first saw it and gave it an upvote and in the comments defend keeping the question.

[What are good books for learning about proof assistants for Functional Analysis?](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/q/256/5)

It currently has two down votes, 4 close votes, 14 upvotes, 9 answers and is has not been closed.