# Does [theorem-proving] need to exist?

Tags: discussion, tags

I think the [theorem-proving](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theorem-proving) tag should be deleted, because it is too general - almost every question will be related to theorem proving. Should it be deleted?

Answer (score 10):

I suspect that this tag was intended to refer to *automated* theorem proving, as queried about at [Is this for assistants only, excluding automated provers?](https://proofassistants.meta.stackexchange.com/q/73/98).  Perhaps it should just be renamed?