# Are questions about automated theorem provers on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, scope

I asked the [what is needed to move from design by contract to using a proof assistant?](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/2225/what-is-needed-to-move-from-design-by-contract-to-using-a-proof-assistant)

not realizing that proof assistant seems to imply interactivity.
I now realize I meant something else - automated theorem provers - perhaps.

I want to rephrase my question but:

1. It would slightly invalidate the answer so far - providing a moving target is not good

also:

2. Are questions about automated theorem provers even on topic?

(the [help](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/help) text is still the standard SE one)

Looking at [How are we doing in beta?](https://proofassistants.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65/how-are-we-doing-in-beta) this site appears to be low on traffic and might not make it out of beta (I may have this wrong).

Would it make sense to rescope it to include all manner of tools for assisting with proofs and/or formal methods?

Related I've just asked [Does a proof assistant have to be interactive?](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/2228/does-a-proof-assistant-have-to-be-interactive)

Comment: I think both of these questions are on topic since they ask about proof assistants. See also [Is this for assistants only, excluding automated provers?](https://proofassistants.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73/is-this-for-assistants-only-excluding-automated-provers)

Comment: Have you searched this meta to see if it was asked before?

Comment: I did but my search failed to find [Is this for assistants only, excluding automated provers?](https://proofassistants.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73/is-this-for-assistants-only-excluding-automated-provers) beforehand . A nuance here was also asking if given the low volume of traffic the scope might have expanded and noting the help text says nothing useful

Comment: I'd guess the tag ([meta-tag:on-topic]) would be suitable here.  (And possibly ([meta-tag:scope].) I do not have enough reputation to edit on meta - so I just mentioned this in a comment.

Comment: Done. Though I am unclear of the difference between "scope" and "on-topic"